# Field 'id' expected a number but got <taggit.managers._TaggableManager object

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, tags

I am building a BlogApp i am stuck on an Error.

**What i am trying to do :-** ( What i want it to do  )

I am filtering users with similar `tags`. BUT when i try to filter then the error is keep showing -

> Field 'id' expected a number but got <taggit.managers._TaggableManager object at 0x0000015B266D3288>.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    interests = TaggableManager(verbose_name='interests')
```

views.py

```
def test_hobbiesss(request,user_id):

    users = Profile.objects.filter(interests=request.user.profile.interests)

    context = {'users':users}
    return render(request, 'list.html', context)
```

**What have i tried :-**

- I also tried by

```
    users = Profile.objects.filter(interests=request.user.profile.interests.all())
```

BUT it shows this error

> The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Any help would be much Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Are you trying to get the users who have same interests as the logged in user?

Comment: Yes sir, I am trying exactly as you said

Comment: In that case, please update your question to reflect it because that provides more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
users = Profile.objects.filter(interests=request.user.profile.interests.all())
```

This fails with the error:

> The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.

Because, you are searching directly in `interests` which is an exact lookup. Because, interests of a user could be multiple, you need `__in` lookup:

```
users = Profile.objects.filter(interests__in=request.user.profile.interests.all())
```

Please note, that this will also get the profile of the `request.user` so if you need to exclude that you can append `.exclude(user=request.user)`.

> If user_1 have set two interests then this code is showing users if one of tags have similar to other users, BUT i am trying to show if more than 2 tags are similar then show users.

In this case, you can `annotate` on interests and use `filter`:

```
users = (
    Profile.objects.filter(
        interests__in=request.user.profile.interests.all(),
    ).annotate(
        interests_cnt=Count('interests'),
    ).filter(
        interests_cnt__gt=1,
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much , It Worked, AND i also used `.distinct()` for exclude duplicate results. BUT what if i want to show users who have more than 1 similar results ?

Comment: I mean, If `user_1` have set `two` interests then this code is showing users if one of tags have similar to other users, BUT i am trying to show if more than 2 tags are similar then show users.

Comment: Excellent, your welcome! I also updated my answer in case you want to exclude the current user from the list.

Comment: Please check the updated answer to match users with more than one interests. I haven't tested it but something along those lines should work.